# Redesigned website, transferred content, and now invisible to Google

Tags: wordpress, google-index, migration

I recently completely redesigned my website, `http://concourstee.fr`. We used to have a fairly good ranking in Google, but when redesigning the website I thought I'd try to make things better. (WordPress Yoast plugin for SEO, better use of keywords, etc.)

So I moved the old website to `http://concourstee.fr/old/` and uploaded the new version of the website. (Both versions are running WordPress)

Since then, my website has just completely disappeared from Google, I have absolutely no idea why... I realized that Google only found the old website, under `concourstee.fr/old/` when doing a search for `site:concourstee.fr`, so I moved it downloaded a backup of the old website and deleted it. Google can still only find `concourstee.fr/old/`, about a week afterwards, and it still won't display the new website, even when searching for things as basic as "Concours Total EDHEC Entreprendre", which is the actual name of the site, and appears several times on the main page.

I then realized I had an error in my code :

```
<meta name="robots" content="none" />
<meta name="googlebot" content="none" />
```

Which I fixed two days ago, changing `none` to `index,follow`, but I am still not appearing in Google...

So what am I to do? We have a big event coming up and we really need our Google visibility back!

Comment: Just for information, `none` value as content for this meta tag is invalid and `index, follow` is the default value. Therefore, you can just remove the meta tag.

Comment: `content="none"` does the same as `noindex,nofollow` for the record.

Comment: I know but it's not a valid value ([source](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html)).

Comment: The Wordpress theme I was using had "none" as a default value, no idea why anyone would want that as a default...

Comment: @Zistoloen Your source doesn't actually say it is not a valid value, it just doesn't mention it. Regardless of whether it is "valid" or not, the fact is, usage of it, does do something - completely deindexes a website so whether it is valid or not is irrelevant. [Google claim it to be a valid tag with the equivalent of noindex, nofollow](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag).

Comment: You can read again the source: `Valid values for the "CONTENT" attribute are: "INDEX", "NOINDEX", "FOLLOW", "NOFOLLOW".`

Answer (score 1):

The disallowing of indexing/following with the `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NONE">` will be the reason that your website disappeared from Google's index. You've since amended this but you'll have to wait for GoogleBot to revisit your website, crawl all pages and reindex them again now. You can speed up this process with:-

- Linking to your website from somewhere else (anywhere), ideally a followed link.
- Submitting your sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools.
- Pinging your sitemap using a service such as [this one](http://www.pingsitemap.com/).
- +1'ing (sharing) some pages from your website on Google+.

It would also be recommended to prevent [everything](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3ahttp://concourstee.fr/old) at `/old` from getting indexed by either:-

- Manually requesting the removal of each URL in Google Webmaster Tools.
- Inserting a `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` into the `<head>` on the entire `/old` directory.
- Adding a disallow directive in your `robots.txt` such as `Disallow: /old/`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply !
I have quite a few people linking back to my site, partners and such, I've received quite a few links as of late.
I resubmited my sitemap and used that ping tool (although only Google and Bing were notified for some reason ?). I'll share on Google° ASAP.

As for /old/, I deleted the folder, and added Disallow: /old/ on my main robots.txt, how long before Google understands and removes /old/ ? I have many search results under /old/, do I really have to go through each link and ask for their removal ?

Comment: If you've deleted `/old` from the server now, it shouldn't take Google too long to remove this from their index depending on how frequently they visit your website. You could just 301 redirect everything at `/old` to the `/` instead in the meantime while you wait for Google to update it's index.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I guess you have a duplicate content issues between old and new site. Google doesn't know which site it must display in its index. That's why when you type `site:concourstee.fr` on Google, you find some URLs from the old site and others from the new site (for your information, if Google discovered the old site, this is because Googlebot found a link to it, thus check your new site links don't point to the old one).

To fix your problem, you can remove the `old/` folder, return 410 HTTP status for all old URLs and block the folder in your *robots.txt*. Then, you can let Google removing old URLs by its own (410 HTTP status is here for this) or ask removal from your Google Webmaster Tools account; in two cases, it takes time (can be weeks or months) to remove all old URLs from Google index. By following this procedure, you should see the new site URLs showing up in Google index because your duplicate content issues will have gone.